# How to enter text with Calabash iOS, Cucumber and NumberPad?

Tags: cucumber, calabash-ios

When I try send text with

```
keyboard_enter_text "12"
```

then I get

```
no visible keyboard (RuntimeError)
```

Because of keyboard type is NumberPad. It is present on the screen.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

How I solve the issue?

First, my screen looks like:
[image: It is not regular keyboard]

To understand that I call next command:

```
BUNDLE_ID={YOUR BUNDLE ID} DEVICE_ENDPOINT=http://{YOU DEVICE IP}:37265 bundle exec calabash-ios console
start_test_server_in_background
query("APNumberButton")
```

And I get my Keyboard structure.

I would like to use simple function in my test to touch this keyboard. That is why I wrote helper:

```
def number_pad(string)
    for i in 0..string.size
        case string[i]
        when "1"
            i_tap("APNumberButton index:0", $CLIENT_TIMEOUT)
        when "2"
            i_tap("APNumberButton index:4", $CLIENT_TIMEOUT)
        when "3"
            i_tap("APNumberButton index:8", $CLIENT_TIMEOUT)
        when "4"
            i_tap("APNumberButton index:1", $CLIENT_TIMEOUT)
        when "5"
            i_tap("APNumberButton index:5", $CLIENT_TIMEOUT)
        when "6"
            i_tap("APNumberButton index:9", $CLIENT_TIMEOUT)
        when "7"
            i_tap("APNumberButton index:2", $CLIENT_TIMEOUT)
        when "8"
            i_tap("APNumberButton index:6", $CLIENT_TIMEOUT)
        when "9"
            i_tap("APNumberButton index:10", $CLIENT_TIMEOUT)
        when "0"
            i_tap("APNumberButton index:7", $CLIENT_TIMEOUT)
        end
    end
end
```

I call it every time, when app use this keyboard.